# VUE3 - Custom Input to format phone numbers. Can't get to work with v-model in parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i made this custom input that basically takes user input and watches and applies some regex magic to format phone numbers.

```
<template>
    <div class="relative flex items-center w-full" style="direction: ltr">
        <span class="absolute block ml-3 pointer-events-none">+20</span>
        <input
            ref="input"
            v-model="number"
            type="text"
            class="w-full border-gray-300 py-2 pr-3 pl-10">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, watch} from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'XPhoneInput',
    setup() {
        const number = ref('');
        
        watch(number, () => {
            number.value = number.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
                .replace(/^(\d{2})?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?/g, '$1 $2 $3')
                .substr(0, 12);
        });
        
        return {number};
    }
};
</script>
```

here's the tag in the parent

```
<x-phone-input v-model="form.phone" />
```

and i'm having troubles making it work with the parent's v-model.
i did a few basic inputs in vue2 where the child component gets the value as a prop and emits the update event and that worked back then, but i just can't get that to work here. or i guess i'm just confused how to make it work with the watcher.
i tried a few combinations of the passing down values and emitting events. but nothing worked for me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works the same: you get it as a prop and send events when it changes. Could you include what you tried so we can see if there’s something wrong with that?

Comment: tried to paste code but its not formatted. screenshot instead

https://prnt.sc/20numq2

Comment: You’re saying it emits `update:modelValue` but you’re emitting just `update`. That’s probably the issue

Comment: oh my lord that was it, thank you so much, in all the googling i did i didn't see it reference the prop name so i just assumed the emits was a flag. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sami Kuhmonen** pointed out what i was doing wrong, which was not declaring the prop name with the emit
here's the working code

```
export default {
    name: 'XPhoneInput',
    props: ['modelValue'], //added the prop
    emits: ['update:modelValue'], //component emits the updated prop
    setup(props, { emit }) {
        const number = ref('');
        
        watch(number, () => {
            number.value = number.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
                .replace(/^(\d{2})?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?/g, '$1 $2 $3')
                .substr(0, 12);
            
            emit('update:modelValue', number.value); //here's what i did wrong, didn't add the prop name to the event name. adding it fixed it. this works
        });
        
        return {number};
    }
};
```